# Do I need to downgrade python from 3.8.2 to 3.7 to run the Anaconda Python 3.7 installer?

Tags: python, conda

I've installed python 3.8.2 and now want to install Anaconda, but there are two versions for macOS: installer for python 3.7 and installer for python 2.7

Does that mean I need to downgrade from 3.8.2 to 3.7.0 for Anaconda? or is the Anaconda installer 3.7+?

Cheers!

https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#macos

Comment: Short answer: No. Just follow the instructions for the visual installer.

Answer (score 1):

A Python installation from python.org and an Anaconda installation are 2 completely different things and they can live side by side. You don't need to do anything with your existing installation. However, **stick to the Anacoda default settings**: Don't add Python to your PATH, as this will probably conflict with your other installation. And let conda intialize your command shells. This will add ../Anaconda3/condabin to your PATH and the only thing you need to do before using Anaconda Python is to activate Anaconda, either by using the **Anaconda prompt** or from your shell via

```
> conda activate
(base) > python
```

You can tell from the prefix (base) in the command prompt that Anaconda has been successfully activated.